# How Can we use Trend Function in Power BI with Constant set to False(0) with DAX

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have an excel sheet that uses the TREND function to calculate the value of Y. For Some Reason, I am not able to set the constant in my DAX to 0. I have re-used the code [Simple linear regression in DAX](https://xxlbi.com/blog/simple-linear-regression-in-dax/) but I can only get the result based on constant SET to true.

I have attached two different Images to compare the changes.

Thanks

[When Constant Set To 1 Note: the changes in a Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWjLx.png)

[When Constant Set To 0 Note: the changes in a Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dTkD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to the article you linked, *Slope* would be redefined as:

`= Sum_XY / Sum_X2`

and *Intercept* redefined as 0.